# Convert Json to DataFrame using pandas

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have a json file that looks like that, and i want to convert it to dataframe while Android and Ios will be my indexes at my DF:

```
json = {
   "Android":{
      "lastExecutionID":"21-08-16_07_02_25_25111",
      "lastExecutionTime":1629,
      "avgDuration":26884
   },
   "IOS":{
      "lastID":"21-08-16_07_02_25_25534",
      "lastTime":1669,
      "avg":109802
   }
}
```

The best way I have found to do this is to convert each json object to list will using my indexes at my DF,
onw list of each key will using 'colmuns' at my DF and one list for each value.
There is a better way to that ?
Thanks everyone

Answer (score 0):

As you want `Android` and `Ios` to be the indexes of the resulting dataframe, see whether this is what you want:

Use [`pd.Series`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.html) + [`.apply()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html), as follows:

```
df = pd.Series(json).apply(pd.Series)
```

**Result:**

```
print(df)

                 lastExecutionID  lastExecutionTime  avgDuration                   lastID  lastTime       avg
Android  21-08-16_07_02_25_25111             1629.0      26884.0                      NaN       NaN       NaN
IOS                          NaN                NaN          NaN  21-08-16_07_02_25_25534    1669.0  109802.0
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest to parse json objects to pandas is `pd.json_normalize()`:

```
>>> df = pd.json_normalize(json)
>>> df
   Android.lastExecutionID  Android.lastExecutionTime  Android.avgDuration               IOS.lastID  IOS.lastTime  IOS.avg
0  21-08-16_07_02_25_25111                       1629                26884  21-08-16_07_02_25_25534          1669   109802
```

Nested names are `.`-separated, so you then just need to split column names and unstack:

```
>>> df.columns = df.columns.str.split('.', 1).map(tuple)
>>> df.loc[0].unstack()
            avg avgDuration          lastExecutionID lastExecutionTime                   lastID lastTime
Android     NaN       26884  21-08-16_07_02_25_25111              1629                      NaN      NaN
IOS      109802         NaN                      NaN               NaN  21-08-16_07_02_25_25534     1669
```